# Force image to stay between height & width "boundaries", as well as keep aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, scale

I wish to keep an image between a minimum and maximum height & width, and at the same time respect the aspect ratio (so if an image needs to be scaled down it would scale down keeping aspect ratio, until both width and height parameters are below the given `max-width` and `max-height`)

It tried the following css:

```css
.box {
  min-width: 128px;
  min-height: 128px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 256px;
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<img class="inner" src="https://i.imgur.com/3t7YAt8.png"/>
</div>
```

However, when running above it directly shows the `max-height` is just ignored and the image only respects the `max-width` constraint. (can be shown by modifying `max-width`, the image will scale that way).

If I change the css for the image itself to use `max-width` and `max-height` instead of width/height attribute the image no longer scale keeping the aspect ratio.

```css
.box {
  min-width: 128px;
  min-height: 128px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 256px;
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
  background-color: cyan;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<img class="inner" src="https://i.imgur.com/3t7YAt8.png"/>
</div>
```

As a side point: in the example, the image is a square, this isn't always the case.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the image to maintain aspect ratio, use css property "object-fit: contain;" on the image tag

Comment: While that indeed prevents the image of being rescaled losing aspect ratio, it however also doesn't help with the actual scaling of the div: the image still "takes" maximum width without, pushing "other" content to the sides. (as shown by the cyan rectangle).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box {
  min-width: 128px;
  min-height: 128px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 256px;
  position: relative
}

.inner {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<img class="inner" src="https://i.imgur.com/3t7YAt8.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: No, the background should be of same size as the image. Cyan region I expect to be a square right now.

Comment: Nnow it's fixated to stay minimum sizel; instead of filling up to the maximum of 256 pixels.